# jQuery click trigger on radio button prevents the radio button being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm having an issue using `.trigger("click");` on radio buttons to trigger a button in a form.

The following code triggers the button as you'd expect. However, it's messing with the radio button for some reason and preventing it from being selected. Even though it appears checked, it's not?

```
  jQuery(".frm_radio").click(function(){
      jQuery('.frm_button_submit').trigger("click");
  });
```

Could the .trigger being changing the state of the radio button to unchecked, even though it's being clicked?

Is there a workaround for this issue if it exists?

I'm triggering a multi part form's next button, so the user simply makes a selection by clicking a radio button and it progresses to the next section. The issue I'm facing is there are conditional fields in the form that rely on the radio button select to display or not. In this case, they don't display, because the trigger is messing with the radio buttons.

Thanks.

**::UDPDATE::
I'm convinced it's a timing issue. By setting a timeout of 1 second, it functions exactly as intended.**

```
  jQuery(".frm_radio").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.frm_button_submit').trigger("click");
  }, 100);
  });
```

**The correct answer I believe will be ensuring the radio gets checked before the click trigger fires. Any Ideas?**

Comment: May I see your whole code? (HTML, JS)

Comment: Is `'.frm_button_submit'` and `<input type="submit">` or `<button>` element within the `<form>`? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You say you're triggering the button - but where is the logic for handling what happens to the radio button? It should come after the `.trigger()` piece depending on what your full code looks like.

Comment: Hi all.. I've updated my question to include the html structure of the form. Apologies for the unedited dump.

Comment: Instead of trigger the button, what about submitting the form. $('#form_w23b3').submit() ?

Comment: @YeLwinSoe - Thanks but it effectively does the same thing. It seems to be triggering the button (or submitting the form) before setting the radio to 'checked'. That's just a guess though, it might be setting then unsetting or something?!?

Comment: Could you create a 'Code Snippet' that can be 'Run' from here itself to address the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the change event on the checkbox like following :

```
$(".frm_radio").change(function(){
   if(this.checked){
     $('.frm_button_submit').trigger("click");
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried .change in place of .click and it works exactly the same. The issue seems to be with the .trigger("click"); part of the equation. That seems to be responsible for messing with the radio buttons 'checked' status.

Adding the 'if' as you suggested, prevented it from working at all?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var clickEvent = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('input[type=radio][name*=item_meta]:checked').length > 0) {
      $('.frm_button_submit').trigger('click');
      clearInterval(clickEvent);
    }
  }, 100);
});
$(document).on('click', '.frm_button_submit', function() {
  alert('frm_button_submit has been clicked (' + $('input[type=radio][name*=item_meta]:checked').val() + ')');
});
```

```css
.frm_radio input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.frm_radio label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frm_opt_container">
  <div class="frm_radio">
    <label for="field_d141k-1" class="">
                                <input type="radio" name="item_meta[71]" id="field_d141k-1" value="General Enquiry" data-reqmsg="Please make a selection so we know how to direct your enquiry"> General Enquiry</label>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="frm_radio">
    <label for="field_d141k-2" class="selectid">
                                <input type="radio" name="item_meta[71]" id="field_d141k-2" value="Make an Appointment" data-reqmsg="Please make a selection so we know how to direct your enquiry"> Make an Appointment</label>
  </div>
</div>

<br />
<button class="frm_button_submit" type="submit">Next</button>
```

This code works only first time on checking the radio button, since the setIntervel function is cleared. If you need to do some validation in click event and all, we need to again add the setIntervel , on change of the value of radio button.

Comment: Unfortunately this acts the same way. It may have something to do with the order things are being triggered.. that is to say the click trigger is firing before it has a change to set the radio? I'm six hours in on this and I'm ready to throw my computer at a wall ;-()

Comment: But please check this example . When you are clicking clicking 'General Enquiry' I'm keeping its value to a variable(just for testing purpose), and then button click event is triggered. and it displays exactly the clicked checkbox value.

Comment: I've confirmed it's a timing issue. By setting a timeout on the trigger, it functions as intended. The correct answer will be a way to ensure the radio is checked before firing the click trigger.

Comment: @Bevels: I've updated the code with an setIntervel function. Please check whether it suits your context.

Comment: This does work. However, it seems to be working as a result of the timer (which I suggested earlier), but your approach requires additional code. Is there any added benefit to having the set and clear interval? The code under ::Update:: in my question works fine as a "timed approach", although I'd prefer something that actually waits for the radio button to be checked before triggering, as opposed to having a specific time in secs or millisecs.

Comment: this approach actually waits till, you check the radio buttons. But additional effort is needed to handle validations of submit events